# e.preventDefault(); not working on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

Scratching my head on this one.. Have a popup  that a) allows users to interact with it i.e.  menus,  etc and if they want to close click/touch (iPad etc) outside of it. Issue is if I insert "e.preventDefault();" to stop links behind the popup and its parent  the contents of the popup stop working on iPad BUT work fine on desktop browsers....

Has anyone any idea?!

```
<div id="divQuickCartDialogOverlay">
    <div id="divQuickCartDialog">
        <div id="overlayQuickBasket"><!--SELECT MENUS, BUTTONS ETC HERE --></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            // Initial call
            setTimeout(basketExpiryCheck, 60000);

            // old style quick basket
            $('#divQuickCart').mouseleave(function() {
                closeCart('mleave');
            });

            // hide cart dialog if user clicks on background div
            $(document).on('click touchstart', function (e) 

            {
                e.preventDefault();

                var container = $("#divQuickCartDialog");
                if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
                {
                    closeCartDialog();
                }
            });

            checkBasketRefresh();
        });

    </script>


<style>
#overlayQuickBasket { margin:0 auto; }
body, html { height:100%; }
#divQuickCartDialog { height:100%;width:100%; }
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#overlayQuickBasket').each(function() {

        $(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(this).css('top', '50%');
        $(this).css('left', '0px');
    });
    $(window).resize(function() {

        var thisheight = Math.round(parseInt($('#overlayQuickBasket').outerHeight()) / 2);
        $('#overlayQuickBasket').css('margin-top', '-' + thisheight + 'px');

        if(parseInt($('#overlayQuickBasket').outerHeight()) > parseInt($('#overlayQuickBasket').parent().outerHeight())) {

            $('#overlayQuickBasket').parent().outerHeight($('#overlayQuickBasket').outerHeight());
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
</script>
```

Comment: IPad has its own functionlity of "tap" in place of "hover", so it doesn't recognize outside click. It will work if u tap another hover element. I didn't find any work around.

Comment: returnfalse; causes the same issue

@Rajiv007 I've got touchstart referenced

It's also disabling all content i.e. <a>, <input> etc once I've closed the popup as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try that instead:

set attribute tabindex for div `#divQuickCartDialog` :

```
<div id="divQuickCartDialog" tabindex="-1">
     ...
</div>
```

CSS just for style, set `outline` to 0:

```
#divQuickCartDialog {
    outline:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Then replace your document `click` and `touchstart` handler by:

```
$("#divQuickCartDialog").on('blur', function (){
     closeCartDialog();
 });
```

When `#divQuickCartDialog` is opened, you have to set `focus` on it.

Comment: $("#divQuickCartDialog").on('click touch', function (e) 

{
    var container = $("#divQuickCartDialog");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
{
    closeCartDialog();
}
    return false;
});

on('blur') wasn't working so amended your solution (tab-index or outline weren't required). Works like a dream on both desktop and iPad.. thumbs up for getting me most of the way there to the solution though